# Pardot Visitor Activities Api issue

Tags: community, rest-api, error, pardot, b2b

Please help me
I am hitting Pardot Visitor Api but it is giving me error

https://pi.pardot.com/api/visitorActivity/version/4/do/query?api_key=fac72d458ec60911ff440d8d9c39ee96&user_key=f7916d7731f4a5d09a5979c915e72d5f

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the user credentials in the HTTP Header, not in the URL.

Take a look at http://developer.pardot.com/#sample-code. Near the bottom of the PHP example, they show the authHeader should look something like: `Authorization: Pardot user_key=<YOUR_USER_KEY>,api_key=<API_KEY_FROM_AUTH_RESPONSE>`